# snprintf replace numbers with question marks - TouchGFX

Tags: c++

I am currently trying to learn the TouchGFX Gui implementation.

For a simple start, I wanted to create a slider, and a textarea that shows the current value of this slider.

As I have seen in the example projects, changing the text of a textArea you need

1. a textAreaBuffer type `touchgfx::Unicode::UnicodeChar` which is in the end an `uint16_t array`
2. `Unicode::snprintf(textAreaBuffer,BufferSize,"Value: %d",value)`

my current Function for changing the text is this:

```
void MainScreenView::changeTextAreaValue(int slidervalue)
{
    Unicode::snprintf(textArea1Buffer, 3, "%d", slidervalue);
    textArea1.resizeToCurrentText();
    textArea1.invalidate();
}
```

In the designer I added an event on changing the slider value which calls this virtual function.
This is my settings of the text area

[image: textarea Settings]
[image: Text Resource Settings]

But when I run this program, the label shows `??` instead of the expected value as soon as I move the slider

Comment: What is the type of `textAreaBuffer`?...

Comment: That is `touchgfx::Unicode::UnicodeChar` array
which is in the end `uint16_t` as it looks like

Comment: Did you try taking the output of `std::cout << int(*textArea1Buffer) << std::endl;`?... The output should be between `48` and `57`...

Comment: outputs normal numbers like 48, 52

Comment: You are certain that `textArea1Buffer` is indeed the buffer of the text control?  Are you supposed to call some `set` function update the text control?  Also, 3 characters for a text string buffer is not going to be big enough for a lot of integers.

Comment: pretty sure since this is the provided way from touchgfx. 
This is autogenerated for the textbuffer in the MainScreenViewBase.cpp:
`textArea1Buffer[0] = 0;
    textArea1.setWildcard(textArea1Buffer);`

Comment: @Scorix Is `textArea1Buffer[0] = 0;` supposed to terminate the string? If yes, it will do the opposite of what you think...

Comment: good question, I have no idea, this is set in the setup function

Comment: `static_cast` is an invalid type conversion
I printed to the Visual Studio Debugoutput with `OutputDebugString((int(*textArea1Buffer) + ""));`
At the old location and it printed something like this: SDL: %s

Comment: @Scorix Try, `std::cout << reintrpret_cast<char*>(textArea1Buffer) << std::endl;` in that case since it seems that this type can not be safe-casted... `static_cast<>` is a safe cast while `reinterpret_cast<>` isnt...

Comment: ah no, since this does not output to the visual studio console I can only give you the debug output which is: `0x013fdad8 ""`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some additional information as to why you're seeing "?".

TouchGFX uses an excel sheet that allows you to specify which characters you would like to have generated from a particular font, for a particular size (A "typography").

If you, for instance, are using a TextArea with a Wildcard and the characters you're placing in the associated buffer for rendering are not represented in either ..

1. Flash memory
2. Font Cache

... TouchGFX will fall back to the "fall back" character that you've specified for that typography (also in the excel sheet). The default fall back character is "?".

Answer (score 1):

This problem was due to a not defined wildcard range as described [here](https://touchgfx.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/207015345-Using-texts-and-fonts). The software couldn't find any available characters to represent the numbers.